# Grails : Rest Service url without .json extension

Tags: json, rest, grails

How i could use the Rest API in grails without .json extension ? This is basically to test in the Rest Console.

Comment: Send the content-type as `application/json` or `text/json`?

Comment: More info on http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation